# Paypal SDK and IPN callback not working

Tags: paypal, sdk, payment

I'm developing an affiliate script with the Paypal Adaptive Payments SDK. I have the following code:

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), 'PAY',$arrPaypal  ['paypal_return'] , 'USD', $receiverList, $arrPaypal['paypal_return']);
$payRequest->IpnNotificationUrl = $arrPaypal['paypal_callback'];
$payRequest->memo = 'Payment for ' . $arrUserInfo['plan_title'];
$payRequest->trackingId = $intID;
```

However it is not firing the callback script. The url is my http:// ipaddress /script.php. If I set it in the paypal sandbox I get a hit but it's not an adaptive payments response as detailed in the sdk. Could someone please explain how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have gotten the case of the IPN setter wrong. Try ipnNotificationUrl instead of IpnNotificationUrl